# Different proof for Cl(A U B) = (Cl A) U Cl(B)

Tags: general-topology

I have seen some other proofs of this going around, but I made my own and was wondering if anyone could check to see if this works?
"Let *A* and *B* be subsets of $R$ (the real numbers). Prove Cl(A U B) = (Cl A) U Cl(B)."

"$\subseteq$" Let *x* $\in$ Cl(A U B) $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ int (A U B)  or *x* $\in$ bd(A U B) . Case: *x* $\in$ int (A U B) $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ A or *x* $\in$ B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ Cl A or *x* $\in$ Cl B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ (Cl A) U (Cl B). Case: *x* $\in$ bd(A U B) $\Rightarrow$ bd(A U B) $\neq \emptyset$ and *x* $\notin$ int(A U B) $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\notin$ int A and *x* $\notin$ int B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ bd A or *x* $\in$ bd B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ Cl A or *x* $\in$ Cl B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ (Cl A) U Cl(B). Thus, Cl(A U B) $\subseteq$ (Cl A) U Cl(B).

"$\supseteq$" Let *x* $\in$ (Cl A) U (Cl B) $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ Cl A or *x* $\in$ Cl B. Case: *x* $\in$ Cl A $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ int A or *x* $\in$ bd A $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ int (A U B) or *x* $\in$ bd (A U B) $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ Cl (A U B). Case: *x* $\in$ Cl B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ int B or *x* $\in$ bd B $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ int (A U B) or *x* $\in$ bd (A U B) $\Rightarrow$ *x* $\in$ Cl (A U B). Thus Cl (A U B) $\supseteq$ (Cl A) U (Cl B).

Therefore Cl(A U B) = (Cl A) U Cl(B).

Note: Cl A is the closure (sometimes shown with an overbar), int A is the set of interior points, and bd A is the set of boundary points.

Comment: Why you are so doubtful of your proof?

Comment: Not doubtful, just wanted confirmation.

Comment: For readability: "union" in TeX is "\cup". Also, the sort of run-on-sentence style is a bit hard to scan: breaking the logical flow into sentences is less ambiguous, and giving it a little more vertical spacing helps the scanning.

Comment: Personally I find these arguments with lots of case distinctions tiring and boring. There are better ways that provide more insight IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct and works for subsets $A,B$ of an *arbitrary* topological space $X$. However, you can do it easier without considering elements $x$.

"$\subset$" Since $A \subset \operatorname{cl}A$ and $B \subset \operatorname{cl}B$, we get $A \cup B \subset \operatorname{cl}A \cup  \operatorname{cl}B$. The latter set is closed (all finite unions of closed sets are closed), thus $\operatorname{cl}(A \cup B) \subset \operatorname{cl}A \cup  \operatorname{cl}B$.

"$\supset$" We have $A \subset A \cup B$, thus $\operatorname{cl}A \subset \operatorname{cl}(A \cup B)$. Similarly $\operatorname{cl}B \subset \operatorname{cl}(A \cup B)$, therefore $\operatorname{cl}A \cup  \operatorname{cl}B \subset \operatorname{cl}(A \cup B)$.